# MERGE operator for the formation of the reporting table

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Can not solve the task. We need to create a table reporting on workers and their business trips. There is a filled table FUNCT_TASK, in which there is the name of the employee, a multiple of the country of the trip and the number of trips to this country. There is also an initially empty table REPORT_TASK, the columns of which are called as the names of employees. The full script is presented below.

```
    CREATE TABLE FUNCT_TASK (
            PERSON VARCHAR2(100), 
            COUNTRY VARCHAR2(30), 
            REPEAT_NUM NUMBER(3)
        );
    CREATE TABLE REPORT_TASK
        (NAME1 VARCHAR2(30),
        NAME2 VARCHAR2(30),
        NAME3 VARCHAR2(30));

    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','BY',2);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','CN',2);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','BE',2);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','RU',2);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','AU',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','AR',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','DK',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name1','EG',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name2','BY',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name2','CN',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name2','UK',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name2','AU',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name2','RU',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name2','DK',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','IT',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','IL',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','BY',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','DE',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','IN',2);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','JP',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','RU',3);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','CN',1);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','BE',2);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','EG',6);
    Insert into FUNCT_TASK_RESULTS (PERSON,COUNTRY,REPEAT_NUM) values ('name3','CA',1);

    COMMIT;

It is necessary to insert / update the data in the REPORT_TASK table so that the result will be presented in the form:

    -----------------------
    name1     name2   name3
    -----------------------
    AR*1      AU*1    BE*2
    AU*1      BY*1    BY*1
    BE*2      CN*1    CA*1
    BY*2      DK*1    CN*1
    CN*2      RU*1    DE*1
    DK*1      UK*1    EG*6
    EG*1      null    IL*1
    RU*2      null    IN*2
    null      null    IT*1
    null      null    JP*1
    null      null    RU*3
```

According to the condition of the task, it is necessary to use the MERGE operator when solving (PIVOT is impossible).

Comment: SO ist not a homework service, tell us what did you try?

Comment: A few questions. (1) Why is PIVOT impossible? Oracle version <= 10.2? Otherwise, why? (2) Why is it **necessary** to use MERGE? Perhaps MERGE is indeed the best way to populate the second table, but that can't be part of the problem REQUIREMENT; if it is, it would be very interesting to hear WHY. (3) is the list of person names fixed and known beforehand? Otherwise how can you even set up the second table - if you don't even know how many columns it will have?

Comment: Another question - are you sure the second "table" should really be a table and not a view? If it's a separate table, how are you going to keep the two tables in sync? Or do you expect that the first table is set in stone (never to have any further DML operations on it)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to generate the data:

```
select max(case when person = 'name1' then country || '*' || repeat_num end),
       max(case when person = 'name2' then country || '*' || repeat_num end),
       max(case when person = 'name3' then country || '*' || repeat_num end)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by person order by person) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

You can insert this into the table by prepending the statement with `insert into report_task (name1, name2, name3)`.